# How to configure Eclipse to handle multiple versions of a file

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am currently writing some mex files for Matlab and every mex files has to contain a function `void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])` so that I can call these files from a Matlab script. For example I have the following files, each containing the `mexFunction`

- `MatlabProjectfolder\computationVersion1Vectors.cpp`
- `MatlabProjectfolder\computationVersion1Pointers.cpp`

However I also want to test the methods without the Matlab overhead. That's why I want to be able to compile my different files in an c++ IDE like eclipse. However eclipse is complaining about multiple declarations of `mexFunction` How can I fix this without making several build configurations in which I exclude all versions of my method except for one? I have more than 10 versions which I want to try and creating those build configurations is just not flexible enough.

Comment: why dont you use git or any other version control tool?

Comment: Maybe because I am not confident enough with git, but I also want to easily test the performance of different implementations against each other. And I have several functions which also have different versions and I want to be able to compile them in eclipse or something alike

Comment: then try it, is not so hard as it looks like... go git it!! :-)